# How do I run periodic tasks with celery beat?

Tags: python, django, redis, celery, celerybeat

Why i can't run a periodic tasks?

**proj/settings.py**

```
REDIS_HOST = 'localhost'
REDIS_PORT = '6379'
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379'
BROKER_URL = 'redis://' + REDIS_HOST + ':' + REDIS_PORT

CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'task-first': {
        'task': 'app.tasks.one',
        'schedule': timedelta(seconds=1)
    },
    'task-second': {
        'task': 'app.tasks.two',
        'schedule': crontab(minute=0, hour='*/3,10-19')
    }
}
```

**proj/celery.py**

```
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'proj.settings')

app = Celery('proj')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')

app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
```

**proj/__init.py__**

```
from .celery import app as celery_app

__all__ = ['celery_app']
```

**celery -A proj worker -l info**

```
[2019-10-31 16:57:57,906: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to redis://localhost:6379//
[2019-10-31 16:57:57,912: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
[2019-10-31 16:57:58,927: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone
[2019-10-31 16:57:58,951: INFO/MainProcess] celery@lexvel-MS-7A72 ready.
```

*Tasks are found*

**celery -A proj beat -l info**

```
Configuration ->
    . broker -> redis://localhost:6379//
    . loader -> celery.loaders.app.AppLoader
    . scheduler -> celery.beat.PersistentScheduler
    . db -> celerybeat-schedule
    . logfile -> [stderr]@%INFO
    . maxinterval -> 5.00 minutes (300s)
[2019-10-31 16:58:02,851: INFO/MainProcess] beat: Starting...
```

The `celerybeat-shedule` file is created. But besides these lines nothing more is displayed.

**tasks**

```
@task()
def one():
    print('start 1', datetime.now())
    driver = init_driver()
    parse(driver)
    driver.close()
    driver.quit()
​
​
@task()
def two():
    print('start 2', datetime.now())
    driver = init_driver()
    parse2(driver)
    driver.close()
    driver.quit()
    print('end 2', datetime.now())
```

Answer (score 10):

---

## Celery beat command

```
celery -A proj worker -l info -B --scheduler django_celery_beat.schedulers:DatabaseScheduler
```

This command has used for start the celery beat.

Firstly add the `django_celery_beat` module in installed apps in settings file.

And then apply the django `migrate` command, this will create the tables in admin pannel.

After completing all the process like in celery file and create task in `tasks.py`.

you will apply the beat command as mentions in above.

---

**proj/settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [

    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'django_celery_beat',
]

REDIS_URL = "redis://localhost:6379/1"

CELERY_BROKER_URL=REDIS_URL

CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND=REDIS_URL

CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']

CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'

CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'

CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE = {

        'task-first': {
        'task': 'app.tasks.one',
        'schedule': timedelta(seconds=1)
       },
      'task-second': {
        'task': 'app.tasks.two',
        'schedule': crontab(minute=0, hour='*/3,10-19')
      }
}
```

**proj/celery.py**

```
from celery import Celery

from django.conf import settings

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'proj.settings')

app = Celery('proj')

app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')

app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
```

**proj/__init.py__**

```
from .celery import app as celery_app

**__all__** = ['celery_app']
```

Comment: If I not write this line `BROKER_URL = 'redis://' + REDIS_HOST + ':' + REDIS_PORT + '/0'` I get error  `(403) ACCESS_REFUSED - Login was refused using authentication mechanism AMQPLAIN. For details see the broker logfile.`

Comment: This is confusing... Are you using Redis as broker, or RabbitMQ???

Comment: Here I have used the redis as a broker
firstly you have to need install the redis-server, then you use the redis easily.
But you could use RabbitMq as a broker.

Comment: @DejanLekic I use `redis` as broker and I not understand why get error related with `RabbitMQ` if I remove `BROKER_URL = 'redis://' + REDIS_HOST + ':' + REDIS_PORT + '/0'`

Comment: The command to start the beat also starts a worker. I suggest you do not do this, unless you are in the development environment.

Comment: Could you please give me some reason why we don't use this command.

Answer (score 2):

When you ran your worker, did it say that `app.tasks.one` and `app.tasks.two` are registered tasks? If they do not appear there as registered tasks then your beat is scheduling tasks that can't be executed. - They will just wait in the queue, and eventually expire. Another way to check whether you have them registered is via `celery -A proj.celeryapp inspect registered` (change `proj.celeryapp` to whatever is the location of your Celery application).

Comment: When I run a `worker` I get list of my tasks `[tasks]
  (app.tasks.one;
  app.tasks.two)
`

Comment: If I write `celery -A proj.celery inspect registered` I get error `Error: No nodes replied within time constraint.` and worker crashes with error `Cannot route message for exchange 'reply.celery.pidbox': Table empty or key no longer exists.
Probably the key ('_kombu.binding.reply.celery.pidbox') has been removed from the Redis database.
`

Comment: Are you getting this error while at least one worker is running?

Comment: I was downgrade `kombu` to `4.6.3` version and run this command `celery -A proj.celery inspect registered`. On the output I get `-> celery@user: OK (
    * app.tasks.one; 
    * app.tasks.two)
`