# Can I reduce number of requests made to redis data store when using celery and beat

Tags: django, celerybeat, django-celery-beat

I am using on a project Django + celery + beat. Is there a way how to reduce number or requests made to redis data store?

THe project runs on fly.io. Part of the fly.toml

```
[processes]
  app = "gunicorn --bind :8000 zzrec.wsgi"
  beat = "celery -A zzrec beat -l info -S django"
  celery = "celery -A zzrec worker -l INFO"
```

The project - dev version - is running on free tier on fly. But I am getting `ResponseError: max daily request limit exceeded. Limit: 10000, Usage: 10000.` message from upstash https://upstash.com/docs/redis/troubleshooting/max_daily_request_limit

So I want to find out if it is possible to modify settings of celery or beat so it will not thit 10.000 requests.

I need celery to run "background" tasks but expecially for dev environment it would be good enough if the are "checked" every minute or so. Not every second.

**UPDATE**
I can see that someone already voted to close this question.. So to make sure

- I am not the author of the code of the working project mentioned above
- I am owner of the project but I am not a programer
- I DID Google search and did not find answer to my question
- the programer that set up Django + celery + beat does not know answer to that question

Comment: if you vote to close it would be nice and useful to say way. thank you

Comment: This is a very broad and vague question. Could be more specific, e.g. share how redis and celerybeat are set up? How many requests are being done, how many requests you expect. What have you tried yourself to solve this problem?

Comment: @NicoGriffioen, did I address your points?

Comment: See https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/ec636fad813320bfb2a860cf69712702dcc530cb/celery/beat.py#L631-L649 for how celery-beat sleeps and wakes up.

Comment: It seems to me that the answer is adjust function https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/ec636fad813320bfb2a860cf69712702dcc530cb/celery/beat.py#L290 am I right? But to be honest I cannot see the asnwer ...

Answer (score 1):

Check first if adjusting the [`CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE`](https://github.com/celery/django-celery-beat/blob/1da72d6838a080ff26baf7f0fb5c942f2958dd3a/django_celery_beat/templates/admin/djcelery/change_list.html#L14) could help, especially if your main goal is to manage the frequency at which tasks are scheduled and reduce the number of requests made to Redis. (a bit like in "[How do I run periodic tasks with celery beat?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58658363/6309)")
Since each task execution potentially involves communication with Redis (for task state management and result storage), reducing the frequency of tasks should lead to a proportional reduction in Redis requests.
Adjusting the beat schedule is generally straightforward and does not require deep changes to your application's codebase. It is a matter of configuration changes rather than code changes.

```py
CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'less_frequent_task': {
        'task': 'myapp.tasks.some_task',
        'schedule': crontab(minute='*/10'),  # Every 10 minutes
    },
    # Other tasks
}
```

That configuration would schedule `some_task` to run every 10 minutes, reducing the frequency from a potential default of running every minute or even more frequently.

The `CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE` configuration is typically done within your [Django project's settings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/settings/), most often the `settings.py`, which contains various configurations for your Django application.

```
myproject/
│
├── myproject/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── settings.py      # Django settings file
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
│
├── myapp/               # Your Django app
│   ├── migrations/
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── tasks.py         # Celery tasks
│   └── ...
│
├── manage.py
└── ...
```

In your project's `__init__.py`, make sure Celery is initialized. This is typically done by creating a new Celery instance and loading the settings from Django:

```py
# myproject/__init__.py

from celery import Celery
from django.conf import settings
import os

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'myproject.settings')

app = Celery('myproject')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
```

When you start your Django project, you also need to run Celery Beat alongside your Celery workers:

```bash
celery -A myproject beat -l info
```

To process the tasks, you need to run the Celery worker:

```bash
celery -A myproject worker -l info
```

---

Overriding the [`is_due` method of a custom schedule class](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/reference/celery.schedules.html#celery.schedules.schedule.is_due) allows you to define your own logic for determining when a task is due to run next. This can be a powerful feature, especially if you need a level of control that goes beyond static schedules defined in `CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE`.

You have to define your custom schedule class. That class should inherit from [`celery.schedules.schedule`](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/reference/celery.schedules.html) or an appropriate base class, and you should override the `is_due` method to implement your custom scheduling logic.

```bash
myproject/
│
├── myproject/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
│
├── myapp/
│   ├── migrations/
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── tasks.py
│   ├── schedules.py  # Custom schedule class defined here
│   └── ...
│
├── manage.py
└── ...
```

With `schedules.py`:

```py
from celery.schedules import schedule

class MyCustomSchedule(schedule):
    def __init__(self, run_every):
        super(MyCustomSchedule, self).__init__(run_every)

    def is_due(self, last_run_at):
        # Implement your custom scheduling logic here
        # Return a tuple (is_due, next_time_to_run_in_seconds)
        ...
```

Next, use instances of your custom schedule class in the `CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE` configuration. You create an instance of your custom class and pass it as the `schedule` parameter.

```py
from datetime import timedelta

CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'my_custom_scheduled_task': {
        'task': 'myapp.tasks.my_task',
        'schedule': MyCustomSchedule(timedelta(minutes=10)),
        # other task options
    },
    # other scheduled tasks
}
```

Make sure that your Celery application is correctly loading the configuration. If you are using a Django project, this typically means ensuring your `settings.py` is properly set up and that your `celery.py` file correctly loads these settings.

After defining your custom schedule class, you can import it in your `settings.py` and use it in `CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE`.

```py
# myproject/settings.py
from myapp.schedules import MyCustomSchedule
from datetime import timedelta

# Celery configuration
# ...

CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'my_custom_scheduled_task': {
        'task': 'myapp.tasks.my_task',
        'schedule': MyCustomSchedule(timedelta(minutes=10)),
        # other task options...
    },
    # other scheduled tasks...
}
```

After making these changes, restart your Celery worker and beat processes to pick up the new schedule.

Comment: Very detailed explanation. I will try what you suggested. Would you know what is default beat frequency?

Comment: Also from reading the very first link you provided. Could I use this? `celery -A myproject beat -l info -S 10`

Comment: @Radek 5 minutes, I believe: see [`beat_max_loop_interval`](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/configuration.html#beat-max-loop-interval).

Comment: but it is a max value. It does not specify the real frequency. That is what I undestoody yesterday when I was reading about max loop interval. But I did not try to change it.

Mayb in my case it is 5s not 5mins. so changing this would help... let me try

Comment: @Radek `-S 10`? Not sure: `-S` is used to specify a custom scheduler class, not an interval.

Comment: @Radek True: The actual frequency at which tasks are checked and run is primarily determined by the scheduled times of the tasks themselves (as defined in `CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE`). If you set `beat_max_loop_interval` to, say, 10 seconds, the scheduler will wake up at most every 10 seconds to check the schedule. However, if there is a task due sooner than that, the scheduler will wake up earlier to dispatch the task.

So, `beat_max_loop_interval` is not a tool for precisely controlling task execution frequency; it is more about managing the scheduler's resource usage.

Comment: I have to try and we will see...

Comment: in the first link you provided is said that `      Periodic tasks won't be dispatched unless you set the
      <code>CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULER</code> setting to
      <code>djcelery.schedulers.DatabaseScheduler</code>,
      or specify it using the <code>-S</code> option to celerybeat` so I thought I could use -S to set what you suggested

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256602/discussion-between-vonc-and-radek).